# Error compiling: undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, header, compiler-errors

I get this error below when I try to compile my program, but I have included the header that contains 'LittleMonkey' class declaration.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Estrellas, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Build started 17/08/2013 0:24:31.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "x64\Debug\Estrellas.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  Missile_mgr.cpp
1>Missile_mgr.cpp(68): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'monkey'
1>Missile_mgr.cpp(68): error C3861: 'monkey': identifier not found
1>Missile_mgr.cpp(79): warning C4482: nonstandard extension used: enum 'MissileEventType' used in qualified name
1>Missile_mgr.cpp(99): warning C4482: nonstandard extension used: enum 'MissileEventType' used in qualified name
1>Missile_mgr.cpp(106): warning C4482: nonstandard extension used: enum 'MissileEventType' used in qualified name
1>Missile_mgr.cpp(113): warning C4482: nonstandard extension used: enum 'MissileEventType' used in qualified name
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:03.21
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Did I do something wrong on these two files?

**Missile_mgr.cpp:**

```
#include "Missile_mgr.h"
#include "Constants.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include "Missile.h"

void Missile_mgr::Test() {

    LittleMonkey monkey(pGame); 

}
```

**Missile.h**, which contains LittleMonkey

```
#ifndef MISSILE_H
#define MISSILE_H

#include "Object.h"
#include "AnimatedSprite.h"

class Game;

class Missile : public Object {
public:
    AnimatedSprite aSp;
    Missile(Game* _pGame);
    virtual void Load()=0;
    virtual void Update()=0; 
    void Draw();

    Game* pGame;
};


class LittleMonkey : public Missile {
public:
    explicit LittleMonkey(Game* _pGame) : Missile(_pGame) { };
    virtual void Load();
    virtual void Update();

};

#endif
```

**Missile_mgr.h**

```
#ifndef MISSILE_MGR_H
#define MISSILE_MGR_H

#include "Quadtree.h"
#include "Missile.h"

class Game;

enum MissileEventType { Wave, WaitForClean, WaitTime, Boss };

struct MissileEvent {
    MissileEventType eventType;
    union {
        int WaitTime;
    } aditional;
};

class Missile_mgr {
public:
    enum MissileType { LittleMonkey, Calamar  };

    bool initialize(Game* _pGame);
    void LoadLevel(int level);
    void Update(); // Update() calls HandleEvents()
    void Draw();
    void Clear();

    std::list<Missile*> missileList;
    sf::Texture txLittleMonkey;
    sf::Texture txBigMonkey;
    sf::Texture txCalamar;
    sf::Texture txFruits;
    sf::Texture txRockets;
    sf::Texture txStars;
    // Do waves?

    float wait;// this is for wait event.
    bool waiting;

    Game* pGame;
private:
    bool HandleEvents();
    void DoWave();
    void DoBoss();
    std::vector<MissileEvent> eventQueue;
    void AddMissile(MissileType* type);

};

#endif
```

Comment: I can add more details

Comment: Can you please add the entire error message ? Is `Missile_mgr` inherited from `Game` ?

Comment: Added!, Game has a Match class, which has a member that is Missile_mgr, but is not inherited.

Comment: Show `Missile_mgr.h`.

Comment: I ask for help on C++ lonunge and they only vote negative but can't answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Missile_mgr {
```

So, `Missile_mgr` isn't inherited from any class.

```
explicit LittleMonkey(Game* _pGame) : Missile(_pGame) { }
```

But the `LittleMonkey` constructor is expecting an argument of type `Game*`.

```
void Missile_mgr::Test()
{
   LittleMonkey monkey(this);
```

And in the above statement, you are trying to cast `Missile_mgr *` to `Game *` which is not possible and compiler is complaining about it.

Answer (score 0):

It took me two hours to figure out the problem was:

```
class Missile_mgr {
public:

    enum MissileType { LittleMonkey, Calamar }; // <- LittleMonkey redefinition
```